# What Date Time Format is this?

Tags: date, datetime

What date time format is this : `735715:37344280`

`<ExecDateTOD Friendly="Monday April 27, 2015  10:23:00am">735715:37344280</ExecDateTOD>`

It's found in `C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\file_name.xml`, and is the date time when the Windows Experience Index Assessment test was run.

Any idea how it's structured and can be edited? I need to change it to a previous years Date.

Comment: Can you find a distinct different example time?  I've not seen the format before (but I don't work on Windows very often).  Do you know anything about the XML definitions that define ExecDateTOD?

Comment: It seems to be related to 'WinSat' [XML Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The number after the colon is probably the number of milliseconds since midnight.  37344280 ms = 10h 22m 24.280s, which is moderately close to 10:23:00am.

Answer (score 1):

For the timestamp **735715:37344280**

The first number (the one **before** the colon) is the number of days since the year 0:

```
735715 / 365 = 2015.66
```

The second number (the one **after** the colon) is the number of milliseconds that have passed **within the current day**.

```
37344280 / (1000*60*60) = 10.37 hours since start of day
```

So you can just subtract 365 days from the first number to obtain the previous year like this:

```
<ExecDateTOD Friendly="Monday April 27, 2014  10:23:00am">735350:37344280</ExecDateTOD>
```

Note that there were no leap years in either 2015 or 2014, so these year are exactly 365 days long.

Here is a link to a page with another `<ExecDateTOD>` tag where you can compare: http://www.scribd.com/doc/82935159/2012-01-30-16-00-49-986-Formal-assessment-Recent-WinSAT#scribd

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this format is called `VariantTime`, in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969199(v=vs.85).aspx) the call to convert time is called `VariantTimeToSystemTime`. So it may be number of days, with decimal part after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you subtract 365 from that number, you'll be in previous year.

That number seems to be days since the year 0. The first part might be the number of days, taking into account leap years, etc). The second part the time coded in some way.

Comment: Divide by 1000*60*60 to get the number of hours since the start of the day.